# Running a loop in a batch file calling on an exe

Tags: sql, windows, batch-file, scripting

I am currently creating a batch file to call on an EXE pulling encrypted passwords from a SQL DB. The EXE handles the API call to the SQL DB so the most of the automation will take place from the EXE.

However, there are 4,000 account passwords that will be pulled from the DB. The EXE is really simple.

There is only one syntax, which includes: `program.exe ServerName TechLogin Password AccountNumber`.

For example:

```
@echo off

REM This script will run an executable to extract encrypted passwords from the SQL DB.

start "Account Password Extraction" /d c:\DEK.exe adv-2k3x86-dc Admin P@ssword 123456789
```

What I am trying to achieve is to add 4,000 AccountNumbers to the batch by looping this process and providing output to either text or xls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance! If you need me to make this more clear then please let me know and I'll do my best to explain.

Comment: Where are you planning to get the account numbers from - are they available in a text file - can you loop through them by simply incrementing a number?

Comment: Does `DEK.exe` return the password in plain text?

Comment: You have to be very carefull using DEK.exe. I don't now if that's the one you're using : http://f.virscan.org/DEK.exe.html

Comment: DEK.exe is a self-made program using C# and the API from the WSDL file downloaded from the IIS files in XML format. This is a trusted application created by myself and my team.

Comment: Forgetting about the output, is there any way that I can loop in 4,000 accounts into this script to have the EXE run against all 4k accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 4k accounts are for exemple in a txt file like this :

accounts.txt

```
account1
account2
account3
...
account4000
```

You can use a simple FOR loop to do that :

```
@echo off&cls
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type accounts.txt') do c:\DEK.exe adv-2k3x86-dc Admin P@ssword %%a
```

Comment: I will certainly give this a try! Thanks for the advice. I will get back to you with my findings. This is why I love this site! So much knowledge to be shared by professionals!

Comment: So, will the script look like this? '@echo off

REM This script will run an executable to extract encrypted passwords from the Connected SQL DB.
start "Account Password Extraction" /d c:\DEK.exe adv-2k3x86-dc Admin P@ssword 123456789

@echo off&cls
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type accounts.txt') do c:\DEK.exe adv-2k3x86-dc Admin P@ssword %%a'

Comment: No, you just have to put the correct DEK parameters in my code. Knowing that %%a represent the accounts recuperated in accounts.txt. You don't have to do a start... Your DEK.exe will be starting automatically in each iteration of the FOR loop, with the new account.

Comment: Thanks for the response sachadee! Let me see how this works out.

Comment: So I ran the script and what it did was just open the text file along with the CMD window open and hanging. I'm just attempting this with one account. Please advise.

Comment: I have no idea how your DEK.exe work and if the parameters to run it are correct in my code. you can test the line putting an ECHO after the DO and a PAUSE at the end, to check if the parameters are OK, If not corrige and then try it with a real account.

Comment: Parameters are correct as I can run it in CMD without any issue with a real account. However, I still get the text file opening with a hanging CMD window. I feel like we are almost there, but there is something missing. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! Stupid me forgot to remove the single quotes from the script calling on the text file.